# I don't understand why title isn't showing on this Magnific Popup

Tags: jquery, html

Here's a link to my page:

http://www.tcgad.com/our-work-2/branding-campaigns/

The JS is actually rendered from a loop, but everything looks right, the titleSrc is inside the image: {} attributes, etc. Still doesn't look like Magnific is passing a title.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

**Edit: SOLVED**
**turns out the "title" attribute was not in the documentation.**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $("#open-content-slider-2541").magnificPopup({
        items: [{
                        src: "http://www.tcgad.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/portfolio_wynn_bb1.jpg",
                        type: "image",
                        title: "Wynn Billboards"
                    },{
                        src: "http://www.tcgad.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/Portfolio_Wynn_Newsletter.jpg",
                        type: "image",
                        title: "Wynn Newsletter"
                    }
],
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        },
        type: "image"
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: You should post the relevant code here. Typically SO users don't like following links to outbound sites aside js fiddles

Comment: ok, thanks. First time poster. Turns out I figured it out- the "title" attribute was completely missing from the documentation!

Comment: @mydoglixu you really have a smiley face at the very bottom of your page? or is that just a bug